# Pure CSS in-page anchoring with dynamic height sticky header issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer, scroll-margin-top

I'm attempting to combine a Pure CSS in page anchoring solution using `scroll-behavior: smooth` and `scroll-margin-top` settings, with a position sticky header in-page navigation.

Using `IntersectionObserver`, I detect the top of the sticky element and add a class to apply specific sticky header styles, which ultimately changes the height of the header.

While the header is in this sticky position, you can click the links in the in page sticky navigation and be taken, smooth scrolling and offset correctly.

The issue is with the initial page load state and clicking an anchor. If you click an anchor while not sticky, you scroll to the correct section but in the wrong offset position. **How can/Can this be fixed without changing to a Javascript solution?**

I've made a crude [Codepen](https://codepen.io/l-triple-o/pen/jOxgNpq) to demonstrate the issues. As an example: On page load click "Section C", you should be taken to the wrong offset. If you click this same "Section C" again , it should be correct along with all others. Your initial click of an anchor while the header is not sticky should take you to the wrong section offset.

Answer (score 0):

The `isSticky` is applied a bit too early. Simply adding a `setTimeout` with a 500ms delay fixes the issue.
Okay... The effect is *a bit* visible, but at least the final positionning is correct.

```
const watchHeader = () => {
  console.log(this);
  const header = document.querySelector(".test");
  console.log(header);
  const ioOptions = {
    root: document,
    rootMargin: "0px 0px -100% 0px",
    threshold: 0
  };
  const ioCallback = ([e]) => {
    console.log(e);
    setTimeout( () => e.target.classList.toggle("isSticky", e.isIntersecting), 500 );  // Here
  };
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(ioCallback, ioOptions);
  observer.observe(header);
};

watchHeader();
```

[Modified CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/BaxXarp?editors=1010)

Comment: Yes, complete win on final position. Yet, with the crude example, adding more accurately sized content to the sections (like 8 more paragraphs of Lorem to each section), the issue persist. Starting at the top clicking "Section D" with more accurately sized content blocks, we are back to square 1. I'm still not understanding why the issue exists in the 1st place? Also, is the only solution to delay an animation until the page is completed its scrolling behavior?

Comment: In the first place, the scroll animation has a duration... And the `isSticky` class should be added when that animation is complete. The page length changes when the class is added, since the header changes its `position` to `absolute`.

Comment: Maybe a `MutationObserver` on the page can be a way to know when the page scrolling ends ? I would look that direction.

Comment: Or simply add a dummy div that has the same height as the header while the header is sticky... That could be easier. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and explanation.  I'll play a bit with these and try to follow up on this later today. I like the dummy div idea too and haven't tried that yet :)

Comment: Yeah... A dummy div at `display: none` from start... which would turn to `display: block` at the same time the `isSticky` apllies... That will be easy to acheive with a class toggle. ;)

Comment: I've tried a few things for this including dummy div. I don't think there is any great way to handle this issue, but I think I found a solution. I now set a click event listener to the anchor nav and detect if the header is sticky or not. From there I add a class to the body that will be available to add CSS for varied `scroll-margin` rules. I've updated my original codepen too https://codepen.io/l-triple-o/pen/jOxgNpq

Comment: Well that works fine! You can post that as an answer ;)

Comment: Is the 171px consistent in all screen size?

Comment: Below 838px (837 and below) for the window width... the issue persists... You will have to add some @media.

Comment: Yes .. to a degree lol. In my use case it's not but media queries handle that pretty good so far. Thanks for all the inspiration too!